# How to get the first data and last data from the same data in the database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to output the time in and time out from this database.
[image]

So i want to get the first data and last data in date 2017-06-13 and 2017-06-15.
How can i do that using Laravel 5.3?

Comment: run query with order by ASC and limit 1, or order by DESC and limit 1 to get result.

Answer (score 1):

May be this will work for you:

```
DB::table('emp')
  ->select(DB::raw("MIN(`time`) AS `time_in`, MAX(`time`) AS `time_out`"))
  ->where('date', '2017-06-13')
  ->get();
```

Output:

```
{
    time_in: "19:38:33",
    time_out: "22:14:10"
}
```

Comment: @Selle Welcome)

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code :

```
$attendancehours = DB::select(
    DB::RAW('TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,CONCAT(in_date," ",in_time),CONCAT(out_date," ",out_time)'))->
    table('staff_attendances')->
    whereBetween('in_date', array($date1, $date2))->
    where('id', $sID)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order your table by the date and time columns and then use Eloquent to take ->first() and ->last() using those methods.

```
$collection = BiometricsAttendance::where('emp_id', $emp)->whereBet‌​ween('date', [$start, $end])->groupBy('date')->orderBy('time', 'asc');

$timein = $collection->first();

$timeout = $collection->last();
```

Comment: $timein = BiometricsAttendance::where(array('emp_id'=>$emp))->whereBetween('date', [$start, $end])->orderBy('date','asc')->orderBy('time', 'asc')->first();
$timeout = BiometricsAttendance::where(array('emp_id'=>$emp))->whereBetween('date', [$start, $end])->orderBy('date','asc')->orderBy('time', 'desc')->first();  From this the output is not what i want. The first date is only the data. i want the 2017-06-13 and 2017-06-15 to be output also

Comment: Do groupBy('date')->orderBy('time', 'asc'), you want to make sure the days stay lined up

Comment: I am getting the first data from both dates 2017-06-13 and 2017-06-15 but the last data i can't. using the first() and last() method takes only the first row and last row of the data in the database.

Comment: It takes the first and last items from the collection object, not necessary whats in the database.